# Why does C# .NET need to be compiled in CLR?

Tags: .net, windows, clr

I know JAVA needs to be compiled in an intermediate language because its Virtual Machine can run on every OS. But as much as I know the CLR only runs on Windows. So why does it need a virtual machine? Is it just a performance thing?

Comment: A managed language like C# also gets compiled to an intermediate language, just like Java.  And also needs a VM to execute, just like Java.  And there are .NET VMs that run on other operating systems, just like Java.  Mono is a well-known one.

Comment: .Net Core 5 will run on Windows, Linux, and Mac apparently: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingNET2015NETAsOpenSourceNETOnMacAndLinuxAndVisualStudioCommunity.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CLR can theoretically run on any platform which has a virtual machine which runs CLR. For example, [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) can be used to run CLR code on Linux.